# How to change Limit on JSON objects being called REACT

Tags: reactjs, json, axios, use-effect

I'm still new to react and calling any sort of API
I can see that I am getting data back, but there is a limit on how much I can get.
I see it says total:467 but limit:50

How can I get all that data back to filter through with my search bar component

```
const[parks, setParks] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  const loadParks = async() => {
  const response = await axios.get(`https://developer.nps.gov/ap/vi/parks?api_key=${API_KEY}
  setParks(response.data.data)
   }
  loadParks()
}, [])
```

I created a live search bar feature that IS working, but I'm only getting 50 results back in my drop down search feature.
The API is for the National Parks

Comment: needs more information. please provide code, ie: what library your making the fetch with, which APis youre hitting, etc to be answered properly

Comment: Hi, this is an API feature and has nothing to do with react. You have probably an option for pagination, skipping or a cursor to the last item. Look in your API Docs for those terms or if publicly available share the API Docs here then someone can help you for sure.

Comment: @MattPengelly I added some code to show how I set up

Comment: There is obviously pagination on the API you are using, refer to the [API documentation](https://www.nps.gov/subjects/developer/api-documentation.htm#/parks/getPark) - you have to change up `start` parameter to get to the next page

Comment: @Agney 
Sorry, very new to this. So I found this on the API docs: 
So, previously, if you hit the /alerts endpoint without using the “start” or “limit” parameters, you would get the first fifty alerts (1-50) for all national parks. To get the next fifty alerts (51-100), you would have made a request like /alerts?start=51. However, now that the start parameter is zero-based, the first query will still return fifty alerts (0-49) and you’ll want your second query to be /alerts?start=50.

Comment: @Agney
I tried setting my url up like so: 
(`https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?limit=100?api_key=${API_KEY}`

but I'm still just getting 50 back.. I feel like I'm on the right track though.

Comment: yeah, it seems like you are on the right track now, i would continue that path and answer this question yourself after you discover what it is. @oliverwebr is likely correct that the API "paginates" the responses, so not to overload the client with a massive amount of data.

leave an answer at the end for other users in case they run into the same issue, and make sure to clarify any unexpected things you experienced.

Comment: Ok yes its paginated as @Agney showed the right API Documentation. You could potentially getting all data by fetching in loop. Where you would take the lenght of your data or the last returned limit +1 as your new start query. But i would not recomand that you do not need it for a search bar. It should be snappy. You got all you need use the `q` parameter to search and you should be good to go.
`https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?api_key=${API_KEY}&q="<search input>"` where `<search input>` is the string your user is searching for.

Comment: To answer you comment `https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?limit=100?api_key=${API_KEY}` is not valid. The question mark is the url starts the query sectiton. You can have just one. But you can still add multiple queries to the section seperating them with an ampersand so:
`https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?limit=100&api_key=${API_KEY}`

Comment: Thank you everyone! I got all my results back! I set up my url how @oliverwebr posted, and it's good to go for now!